# How to compile an if-statement with variable-length instructions

Tags: parsing, if-statement, compilation

I'm writing a little language VM with arbitrary integer (encoding, not literally) parameters, and I'm about to implement if-statements.
The tried-and-true formula for if statements is to compile

```
if (EXPRESSION) {
    BODY
}
```

into

```
EXPRESSION
JUMP-IF-FALSE body-length
BODY
```

However, I'm struggling to see how a single-pass compiler can determine the body length while it's generating the `JUMP-IF-FALSE` command.

With constant-sized instructions, you can just add two extra bytes or something and go back and patch it, but with variable-sized ones that would require either insertion or concatenation, two O(N) processes.

So, my only option appears to be to switch to constant-sized jump instructions and every `MAXJUMP-1` bytes insert a command to jump over the next instruction, and then another `JUMP` instruction.

Even if this situation (65k+ flat bytes with 2-byte jump) is really unlikely I would really, really like to not have do this.

Comment: On the offchance someone needs this, I ended up having a vector of jump destinations and storing an index into the vector instead of a distance in the command. Not sure if that's how you're supposed to do it, but it works.